# Including several classes in one

Tags: php, oop

I was working on my core class which looks like this:

```
require 'core.conf.php';

class Core {
    public function __construct() {
        $autoloader = new classAutoloader();
        $this->instantiateObjects();    
    }

    private function instantiateObjects() {
        $handle = opendir(__DIR__);
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                if ($file != "core.class.php" && !in_array($file, $file_exceptions)) {
                    $class_name = str_replace('.class.php', '', $file);
                                        $this->$class_name = new $class_name();
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}

class classAutoloader extends Core {
    public function __construct() {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
    }

    private function loadClass($class_name) {
        require $class_name . '.class.php';
    }
}
```

It loads all the classes and instantiates them into one core.
So that I would be able to do this:

```
$core = new Core();
```

And access all the loaded classes like this:

```
$core->database->foo();
$core->template->foo();
```

Now that works completely fine, but if I want to use e.g. database in the template class I'd have to add global $core to every function that needs to access the database, but I don't want to global all the time. What's the correct way of solving this? Would it matter if I made all the classes static? I'd prefer using -> instead of :: though. I hope you could help me out!

Comment: Have you tried passing `$core` to a value inside a class like `$fromGlobalCore` and then just use the later? Or am I missing something? :(

Comment: When you instantiate `Core`, where do you use it? on the same page that instantiated it or on others? If it's the latter, then you'll have to pass it around, and `GLOBALS` help in doing that. However, if the same instance of your `Core` class needs to be accessible by another class why don't you use the `Parent` special name to access the base class `Core` ? Am I not getting it? What I meant earlier (my comment before this one) was under the assumption that you wanted to pass `Core` into the class it loaded.. Which should point back to usage of `Parent`, actually :)

Comment: I use it in my index page and only there because I work with a template engine. How would I use the parent special name?

Comment: Here's a link to `parent` info: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php However, it seems that your best bet would be to encapsulate your functions into another class.. then you'll need not use globals.

Comment: And how would I do that? Is it a certain pattern I would use?

Comment: see my post below. I literally can't invite you to chat yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
# classFunctions.php
class classFunctions {
    private $localCore;
    public function __construct($coreInstance) {
        $this->localCore = $coreInstance;
    }

    public function One () {
        # to use/access core:
        $this->localCore->someFunction();
    }

    public function Two () {
        # to use/access core:
        $this->localCore->someFunction();
    }

    # ...and so on

}

# index.php
# include('classFunctions.php');
$core = new Core(); // Your one and only instantiation of class Core
$clsFunc = new classFunctions($core); //
```

This way you don't need to keep using `$GLOBALS`

Comment: But I wouldn't be able to use all the loaded and instantiated classes from the Core class would I?

Comment: You should try it.. It should work since `$localCore` is now an object instance of `Core` which is also `$core`

Comment: But why do I have to instantiate a new object? That takes the purpose of simplicity away. I wanted to have everything happening within one class in one variable.

Comment: Your `Core` class might be a MODEL class. So now that you want to use that class to do stuff in your page based on certain requirements or purpose, you'll best use a CONTROLLER class. See, even if you have template and database classes instantiated in your `CORE` class, if you need to still direct the `CORE` class as to what actions to do, then you'll be better off using a CONTROLLER class to direct its movements. Try http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html and http://www.ericbieller.com/2010/05/20/php-project-planning-for-idiots-mvc-design-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

If you make any `CoreClass` (Database, Template) require to have a `Core` instance, each `CoreClass` knows about `Core`.

If you then tell any loader (your hardencoded autoloader for the default libraries and the SPL based autoloader) which `Core`, those loaders can factor classes with the `Core` instance passed to them.

```
class Core
{
    public function addClassInstance($classname, $name)
    {
        $object = new $classname($this);
        $this->$name = $object;
    }
}

abstract class CoreClass
{
    private $core;
    final public function __construct(Core $core)
    {
        $this->_core = $core;
        $this->init();
    }
    final public function getCore()
    {
        return $this->_core;
    }
    abstract public function init();
    final public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->_core->$name;
    }
}

public function Database extends CoreClass
{
    /* ... */
    public function foo()
    {
        $this->template->foo();
    }
}


$core = new Core;

// load default `CoreClass`'es: template, database
$loader = new CoreDefaultLoader;
$loader->init($core);

$core->database->foo();
```

`CoreClass`'es won't be able to override `__get` with this design, so probably you want to make things less strict here to continue to be more flexible.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that I get a lot of classes in 1 file? The idea was to have a seperate file for every class actually. I'm probably missing something..

Comment: That's only a rough outline. You can add as many loaders as you want, the important part is how `CoreClass`es are instantiated (inject `Core` instance). That's independent to your file-system layout.

Comment: I don't really understand it I'm afraid.

Comment: Bottom-line is: Make each `CoreClass` know `Core`. Then you don't need a global variable. Helpful patterns here are [Dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) and [Abstract Factory](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AbstractFactoryPattern).

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand it. Is there a possiblity you could create an example with my class?

Comment: Well your classes don't reflect what I outlined here, so I can't make an example out of it. I might be able sometime in the future if I have some spare time to make the example in my answer better somehow.